# Pyparsing ParseException

Tags: encryption, sparql, pyparsing

I am tring to insert the following SPARQL query:

sparql_3 = "INSERT {http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Elizabeth http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Allergies "+ repr(final_data) + "} WHERE {http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Elizabeth ?predicate ?object .}"

final_data is a string variable that represents an encrypted data.

The print of the query is :

sparql_3 ::  INSERT {http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Elizabeth http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Allergies '}c£¨\x0bÆpì\x9b]UÖIú\x86_ \x0f7Ò¼$K5eÅÔ4#\x8a3\x8fÏYï\x02ñTÂä\x15\x00°±ÐF!-'} WHERE {http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Elizabeth ?predicate ?object .}

I was trying to run

qres_3 = g.update(sparql_3)

I get the following error:

pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text, found 'I'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Can someone please help?

Comment: sorry, but your question is not understandable: 1) please use Github code formatting to at least encapsulate your queries in preformatted style. 2) you use pyparsing why to execute a SPARQL query on which triplestore? Not that I understand why you encypt something, but a URI in a SPARQL query indeed follows standard URI encoding requirements. Like `http://www.semanticweb.org/umbcknacc/ontologies/2017/10/untitled-ontology-3#Allergies '}c£¨\x0bÆpì\x9b]UÖIú\x86_ \x0f7Ò¼$K5eÅÔ4#\x8a3\x8fÏYï\x02ñTÂä\x15\x00°±ÐF!-'} ` - why is there a whitespace in between? And di you try to URI encode the string?

Comment: (indeed I meant to use StackOverflow code environment to make code like queries as well as possible source code more readable) - thank you

Comment: \x isn't a legal escape sequence in SPARQL.`repr(final_data)` needs to generate a legal SPARQL string and scape the `\` to give `\\x`. Other parts of the string may also be wrong - the string must be legal as UTF-8.